# How to format a link in a comment?

Tags: support

I could not format a link in comments. I tried like
[link][1]

[1]:link.address. But it did not help? So how should I format in comment?

Thanks.

Comment: Click on the 'help' link next to the comment edit box for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its quite easy. Use [] brackets with () following:

```
[google.com](http://ww.google.com)
```

[google.com](http://ww.google.com)

Comment: [google.com](http://ww.google.com) just for proof :p

Comment: [google.com](http://www.google.com) :)